# Continue script after schedule until python

Tags: python, schedule, weather

I would like to continue my python script after the `schedule.every(x).seconds.until(x).do(job)`, but my program end the function until the `x` time and doesn't keep going after.

Here is my program :

```
import requests
import json
import pickle
import schedule
import sys
import time
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from threading import Timer
import matplotlib
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import math
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '/Library/TeX/texbin'

key = 'MY_API_KEY'
adress = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'
params = {'appid':key, 'q': 'Lausanne', 'units':'metric'}

def somme(tab):
    s=0
    for i in range(len(tab)):
        s=s+tab[i]
    return s

def moyenne(tab):
    return somme(tab)/len(tab)

tab=[]
tab2=[]

def function(tab,tab2):

    response = requests.get(adress, params=params)
    weather = response.json()
    temp = weather['main']['temp']
    print(temp)
    tab.append(temp)
    now = datetime.now()
    time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    tab2.append(time)
    print(tab)
    print(tab2)
    print(moyenne(tab))
    
function(tab,tab2)
schedule.every(10).seconds.until("20:00").do(function, tab, tab2)

while True :
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

fig = plt.figure(1,figsize=(9, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
plt.plot(tab2,tab, 'b.')
plt.show()
```

I would like that my program plot the graph after it had done the schedule. Is it possible ?

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT :**

Thank you to Tim Roberts for the answer in the comments !
I just have to change my loop like this `while datetime.now().hour < 20:`

Comment: Do you mean you want the program to exit the loop and continue after 20:00?  Change your loop to `while datetime.datetime.now().hour < 20:`.